# Mac installer with install4j not taking jre folder

Tags: install4j

I am building Mac (10.10.5) Installer with install4j with bundled JRE option in the Media step.

After creating installer when I install my application than the JRE folder is not generate in the application folder. How can I get this?

Answer (score 1):

The location of the JRE bundle on Mac OS X for single bundle media files is in `Content/Resources/jre.bundle`